# How can I check why a Varnish probe fails?

Tags: varnish

I'm used to run

```
varnishadm -T localhost:6082 debug.health
```

to check the backends health status, but how can I check why a probe fails in details (eg timeouts, wrong http status code)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little tricky to find [1] but:

> Every poll is recorded in the shared memory log as follows:
>
> NB: subject to polishing before 2.0 is released!
>
> ```
> 0 Backend_health - b0 Still healthy 4--X-S-RH 9 8 10 0.029291 0.030875 HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
> ```

...

> Notice that the second word indicates present state, and the first
>   word == "Still" indicates unchanged state.
>
> - 4--X-S-RH -- Flags indicating how the latest poll went
>
>   - 4 -- IPv4 connection established
>   - 6 -- IPv6 connection established
>   - x -- Request transmit failed
>   - X -- Request transmit succeeded
>   - s -- TCP socket shutdown failed
>   - S -- TCP socket shutdown succeeded
>   - r -- Read response failed
>   - R -- Read response succeeded
>   - H -- Happy with result
> - 9 -- Number of good polls in the last .window polls
> - 8 -- .threshold (see above)
> - 10 -- .window (see above)
> - 0.029291 -- Response time this poll or zero if it failed
> - 0.030875 -- Exponential average (r=4) of responsetime for good polls.
> - HTTP/1.1 200 Ok -- The HTTP response from the backend.

So you should use varnishlog to get fail details.

[1] https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/BackendPolling#SHMlog

Comment: Thanks @NITEMAN, it's still a bit tricky to me find the root couse of the problem:
    Backend_health - MainProd Still healthy 4--X--- 5 4 6 0.000000 0.145350
No HTTP status code or other hints about the error. Any idea on how to debug it?

Comment: I've extended the documentation excerpt. In your case Varnish perform the request but the backend response never get back to Vanish, so most likely to be a time out. Better check backend logs for the probe results.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot @NITEMAN I'll try to debug the issue on backend side.

Answer (score 7):

In Varnish 4.0 you can see the status of all backends and their recent probe success rate with

```
varnishadm backend.list
```

Comment: `varnishadm backend.list -p` for the old visual list with more detail

Answer (score 3):

At least with varnish 4 you can also use this command for debugging the health probes:

```
varnishadm debug.health
```

Comment: seems like it's `varnishadm backend.list` now